# Use JSON to create a 2 levels group by in a gallery view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, json-formatting

I'm trying to create a 2 level group by in a SharePoint gallery view.
The following code is only displaying one level. In my case, I want to group by **Entity** and them by **Title**.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "hideColumnHeader": true,
  "tileProps": {
    "height": "100"
  },
  "groupBy": [
    {
      "showInView": "all",
      "name": "Level1Field",
      "orderDescending": false
    },
    {
      "showInView": "all",
      "name": "Level2Field",
      "orderDescending": false
    }
  ],
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLight ms-fontColor-black"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-fontColor-black ms-fontWeight-semibold"
        },
        "txtContent": "@currentField.Level1Field"
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-fontColor-black ms-fontWeight-semibold"
        },
        "txtContent": "@currentField.Level2Field"
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-fontColor-black"
        },
        "txtContent": "@currentField.Title"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get this JSON (ChatGPT or similar tool or any article/blog/GitHub sample)? I don't think `groupBy` property is available in the SharePoint JSON formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally in SharePoint, you can add the grouping on columns in the list view from list view settings and not via JSON formatting.

From list view classic experience settings page, you can apply the grouping under "Group By" section like:

[image]

Two levels of grouping works fine in the table/list view in SharePoint online lists:

[image]

But as per my research, two levels of grouping is not supported in the gallery view of SharePoint online lists (Same view as above with Gallery/Tile mode):

[image]